# Where is the content that is outputted by get_the_archive_description()?

Tags: archives

I need an intro text to a custom post type archive, so I want to use get_the_archive_description(). Thing is, I can't figure out where in the admin is the text that is gonna be outputted by this function.

So where is it?

Answer (score 1):

That function starts like this:

```
function get_the_archive_description() {
    if ( is_author() ) {
        $description = get_the_author_meta( 'description' );
    } elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
        $description = get_the_post_type_description();
    } else {
        $description = term_description();
    }
```

so you're looking at `get_the_post_type_description()`.

If you check [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) for `register_post_type()` you'll see that `description` is one of the args that this takes.  So you need to either use a plugin/write code to create a place to add this text in the backend, and then dynamically fill that arg with your custom field content, or you need to add the text in code where you're registering the CPT.